# Stuck plastic tile to basement concrete floor

Tags: tile

I have a basement with some plastic or vinyl tile. The tile is cemented onto the floor. I need to remove it all.

I've checked several YouTube videos about this but they only show ideal situations. My situation is terrible! The tiles are cemented onto the concrete so strongly that the only way I can get them up is by ramming a scraper (razor blade type) at the edges, over and over. It takes about ten minutes for each 12"x12" tile. It's incredibly slow and tiring (and monotonous).

There must be a better way. Chemical? Heat? I tried a heat gun but it did nothing to help. This adhesive is very strong and stubborn.

Does anyone know a trick for this?

BTW I sent in a sample to a lab and luckily it is not asbestos.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation in my basement. I tried a scraper blade attachment with a reciprocating saw with poor results, it was hard to control and get under the tiles.

The only thing that worked for us was a floor scraper that had a long handle. It makes it easier than being on your knees with a hand scraper. Like this one [7" Floor Scraper](https://www.princessauto.com/en/detail/heavy-duty-floor-scraper-with-7-in-blade/A-p8158677e)

Answer (score 1):

Rotary hammer with a 3" sds chisel blade or maybe a 10" chisel like this:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Bosch-Bulldog-Xtreme-2-1-2-in-x-10-in-SDS-plus-Hammer-Steel-Self-Sharpening-Wide-Chisel-HS1427/203621950

or maybe the sds max floor scraper

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Vulcan-6-in-SDS-MAX-Floor-Scraper-Complete-700/202578918

A power tool goes a long way to make hard jobs easier.